# Warning messages after closing Firefox in firejail sandbox mode

Tags: firefox, pipe

I generally use Firefox in sandbox mode using Firejail. Sometimes, I get warning messages when I close the browser, like the following messages...

```
firejail firefox
Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-mgmt.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-secret.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Parent pid 2671, child pid 2672
Blacklist violations are logged to syslog

Child process initialized
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
[Child 176] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 709
console.log: shutdown APP_SHUTDOWN
[Parent 5] WARNING: pipe error (52): Connection reset by peer: file /build/firefox-S0wyi8/firefox-55.0.2+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 353

parent is shutting down, bye...
```

Should I be worried about these messages? Or are they normal?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Consider that they are listed as "WARNING" messages and not critical errors.  I think you can safely ignore those, but you may want to consider that this may be a bug in the software itself, rather than something you should really be concerned with.

Comment: You mean bug in Firejail? Apart from the warning messages,  Firejail is pretty well-designed and reliable right?

Comment: Never said it wasn't, but such "warning' notices usually point to some type of unhandled issue in the code, but that's not necessarily an issue here.  As I said, I think you can ignore the warnings since that's just what they are.

Comment: If you are worried, file a bug report against firejail

Comment: Run bash -x application, this should run the desired application as intended, however it is only advised for developers. Firejail is still a work in progress and littered with bugs that I hope get ironed out in the future. You can always turn to virtual machines for sand boxing.